# "s'élancer" and "se lancer" - what's the difference in meaning in this context?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

> Ce samedi après-midi, ils étaient nombreux à avoir chaussé les patins pour **s'élancer** sur la piste de la patinoire de Louhans.
>
> Ce samedi après-midi, ils étaient nombreux à avoir chaussé les patins pour **se lancer** sur la piste de la patinoire de Louhans.

Can they be both used  with no difference in meaning, or do they have slightly different meanings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have the same meaning and are interchangeable in your examples but there are idioms where *se lancer* is expected, at least that one:

> *Se lancer dans la course*

which means: to declare oneself as a competitor (for an election, a race, etc.)

*S'élancer* is rarely used a figurative way.

We can say:

> Renault se lance dans la fabrication de voitures électriques.

but not

> Renault s'élance dans la fabrication de voitures électriques.

Answer (score 2):

**I** There is only a very small difference and *it can be ignored in certain cases* as for instance in the examle given; this is so because there is a complement telling the particular open space where the action takes place. It's not always too idiomatic or not at all however, when the complement is not an open space;

- Ils se sont lancés/élancés vers la mer.
- Ils se sont lancés dans la mêlée. (***"élancer"*** is [not very idiomatic here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9lanc%C3%A9+dans+la+m%C3%AAl%C3%A9e%2Clanc%C3%A9+dans+la+m%C3%AAl%C3%A9e&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clanc%C3%A9%20dans%20la%20m%C3%AAl%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clanc%C3%A9%20dans%20la%20m%C3%AAl%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0).)
- Il s'est lancé sur elle. (*You [don't say as much](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lanc%C3%A9+sur+elle%2C%C3%A9lanc%C3%A9+sur+elle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clanc%C3%A9%20sur%20elle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9lanc%C3%A9%20sur%20elle%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clanc%C3%A9%20sur%20elle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9lanc%C3%A9%20sur%20elle%3B%2Cc0) "Il s'est élancé sur elle."*, the separating space is too small.)
- Il s'est lancé/élancé vers elle. (*As "towards" is used, there is a space  between the thing/person and the moving person/animal/thing. However, as can be seen from an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lanc%C3%A9+vers+elle%2C%C3%A9lanc%C3%A9+vers+elle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clanc%C3%A9%20vers%20elle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9lanc%C3%A9%20vers%20elle%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clanc%C3%A9%20vers%20elle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9lanc%C3%A9%20vers%20elle%3B%2Cc0) the distinction was extant in the past (before 1940); it's only relatively recently that it stopped being made.*)

The slight difference is that "s'élancer" means "se lancer en avant".

> (TLFi) **se lancer** Emploi pronom. réfl. [En parlant de la pers. elle-même] S'élancer, se jeter impétueusement.
>   Chacun se lance devant soi, attiré par le fossé terrible, raidi en avant
>
> (TLFi) **s'élancer** Emploi pronom. réfl. subjectif.Se lancer en avant. S'élancer dehors; l'oiseau s'élance de son nid.

When there is no complement "se lancer" is not used with the meaning "to rush forward";

- Les pilotes se sont élancés, et ils étaient aussitôt dans leurs voitures.
- <s>Les pilotes se sont lancés, et ils étaient aussitôt dans leurs voitures.</s>
- Les pilotes se sont lancés sur la piste, et ils étaient aussitôt dans leurs voitures.

**II** These verbs are never equivalent in the figurative sense; "s'élancer" is not used like that, only "lancer";

- Ils se sont **lancés** dans la vie sans un sou en poche, et ils ont réussi. (*never **"se sont élancés"***)
  *They took the plunge into life without a penny, and they made it.*
- Le moteur s'est lancé lentement, toussant et remué de secousses brèves. (*never **"s'est élancés"***)
  *The engine started slowly, coughing and shaking briefly.*